# Error (JSONException) when i try to upload image from Android to PHP server with Volley

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have an error that I can't fix when I upoload an image from my android device to a PHP web server. More precisely I get the error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

And I honestly can't understand why. I am attaching the PHP script below, in the hope you managed to identify the error.

```
<?php
// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = dirname(__FILE__).'.';

if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            echo json_encode(array('status'=>'fail', 'message'=>'could not move file'));
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success', 'message'=>'File Uploaded'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'fail', 'message'=>$e->getMessage()));
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'fail', 'message'=>'Not received any file'));
}
?>
```

While the image upload function is defined in this way

```
private void imageUpload(final String imagePath) {

SimpleMultiPartRequest smr = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Response", response);
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String message = jObj.getString("message");

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

smr.addFile("image", imagePath);
MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr);
```

Why do you think I get this error?

Comment: What do you get as response?

Comment: Nothing, I only see that error as a toast notification. I also encountered another error in the console: failed to open stream: `Permission denied in <b> /opt/lampp/htdocs/api_demo/upload.php`

Comment: Solved. `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/matteo/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs`

Comment: @mrmarra98x you should frame this as an answer if it's a quality resolution to your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/matteo/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs
```